# How to overlay java source code like overlay resources in Android?

Tags: android

We know that use this tag "DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS" to overlay resources file, but how to overlay java source code like overlay resources in Android?

Comment: can you explain what you mean? it's not so clear

Comment: In a mk script, use tag "DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS" to overlay resources file while compiling.
eg:
 in XX.mk file:
DEVICE_PACKAGE_OVERLAYS:= device/XX/overlay
then， the files of the dir "frameworks/base/core/res/res" can be overlayed from these files of the dir "device/XX/overlay/frameworks/base/core/res/res". So i want to overlay java source code, i don't know how to do it.